# Tomcat7 port 8080 is closed from outside - Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, server, tomcat7, port

Here it is netstat of port 8080

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24892/java
```

And I did nmap localhost and 8080 port is open

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-13 10:56 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00043s latency).
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
587/tcp  open  submission
3000/tcp open  ppp
3306/tcp open  mysql
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

And I've checked it from outside (IP/Hostname), it is in closed list. I checked in ping.eu and the port is closed

```
nmap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                                   
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-13 10:59 IST
Nmap scan report for ec2-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Not shown: 988 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
2000/tcp closed cisco-sccp
2001/tcp closed dc
3000/tcp open   ppp
3001/tcp closed nessus
4000/tcp closed remoteanything
5000/tcp closed upnp
7000/tcp closed afs3-fileserver
7001/tcp closed afs3-callback

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.64 seconds
```

And my ufw is disabled.

Please help me on this.

Comment: this should probably be migrated to Unix & Linux forum

Comment: Your router is blocking outside connections. You need to configure port forwarding.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry, I don't know how to do that, can you please explain.

Comment: No I can't. I don't have the time to explain things that can easily be found through Google.

Comment: @Kayaman Ya I have tried searching in google but it was bit confusing and will figure out any how.. Thanks for taking out your time and answering.

Comment: Googling for "router port forwarding" should give you plenty of results to go through. Then it's just reading until you understand the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Ya I will go through it, thanks mate!